# Show data in Custom tableview Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I am new to developing. i have some experience but i'm not great at it (yet). I'm working on this tableview app which shows data. I want to show that data in a custom cell. But i don't know how to do that.
This is the code i use for my tableview:

```
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    HistoryTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HistoryViewTableCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HistoryViewTableCell" owner:self options:nil];

        cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    NSDictionary * tempDictionary = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"PickupAddress"];

    return cell;
}
```

I need to show this line of code in my custom cell.

```
cell.textLabel.text = [tempDictionary objectForKey:@"PickupAddress"];
```

I already made a class and a xib file for the custom cell

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Answer (score 0):

This may solve the problem:

```
 HistoryTableViewCell *cell = (HistoryTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HistoryViewTableCell"];
```

Answer (score 0):

your written kind of code will not work. if you are using custom XIB than add a UILable in the xib. and than assign them tag number.

now from ViewController do the following:

1. write this after @implementation

   ```
    enum {
     CELL_TITLE = 2,
     CELL_SUBTITLE_1 = 3,
    };
   ```
2. Load the Custom XIB File in cellforrowatindexpath method.

   ```
   // Get table View Cell
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"customCell";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [atableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) {

       NSArray *nib;
       nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];
       cell = (UITableViewCell *) [nib objectAtIndex:0];
   }
   ```
3. Now Add text on Lable with the below methods;

   ```
   UILabel *titleLable = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:CELL_TITLE];
   titleLable.text = @"This is your text";
   ```